# Converting contents of a character array into ASCII key values

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a Caesar Cipher program i take the users input as a string and then convert that string into a character array i am stuck on converting all of the characters in that array into there ASCII key values because the amount of characters in the array can change every time the program runs depending on what message the user inputted how can i go about checking the amount of chars in the array and then using the number returned to convert all the numbers into ASCII key values

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Message;
    char arr[Message.length() + 1];

    cout << "Please Enter The Text You Would Like To Encrypt(seperate words using _ and only write in lower case)" << endl;
    cin >> Message;

    strcpy(arr, Message.c_str());

    int Length = string(arr).length();
    
}
```

Comment: After `std::cin >> Message;`, `Message[0]` holds the number that represents the first character; `Message[1]` holds the number that represents the second character; and so on. You don't have to do anything to get the numeric values. And you can edit the values directly in the `Message` string. You don't need `arr`.

Comment: Also, at the point where `arr` is defined, `Message` is empty, so `Message.length() + 1` is 1. And the size of an array has to be a compile-time constant, so you can't create that C-style array with a size determined at runtime. Yes, your compiler might allow it, as a non-standard extension; don't count on that. If you decide you really need an array, use `std::vector<char> arr(Message.length() + 1);`.

Comment: You **have** saved it as a s string. That's what `std::cin >> Message;` does. The numbers are in `Message[0]`, `Message[1]`, etc. You can change them. **Try it**.

Comment: I've removed the `arr` as per your suggestion when writing it as you suggest how do i do that relative to the length of `Message` as its length will be different every time the program runs

Comment: This is not a forum. Write some code. If you can't get it working, post it and ask a question.

Comment: The size of an array must be a `constexpr` integral value. `char arr[Message.length() + 1]; // Message.length()` is not  `constexpr` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by taking the length of the string and storing it into a variable declared as an integer to store the string length i used Message.Length()to get the length of the string I then created a for loop to iterate over the length of string i then declared

```
int ASCII_Converter = int(Message[i]) + offset
```

This takes the value of i and uses that at the relevant position in the strong and adds the offset

The if statement is used to check where the ASCII value is equal to 95 to add a space to the text

it then prints out the encrypted string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Offset;
    string Message;

    cout << "Please Enter The Key 1-25" << endl;
    cin >> Offset;
    cout << "Please Enter The Text You Would Like To Encrypt(seperate words using _)" << endl;
    cin >> Message;

    int StringLength = Message.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < StringLength; ++i)
    {
        int ASCII_Converter = int(Message[i]) + Offset;

        if(int(Message[i]) == 95)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }

        cout << char(ASCII_Converter) << "";
    }
    cout << "" << endl;
}
```